# Циклический код для передаваемых данных

Tags: кодировка, java

Добрый день.

Передаю байты данных через последовательный порт RS-232.
Для этого использую jSSC библиотеку для Java.
Нужно защитить передаваемые данные циклическим кодом [7,4]. Но так как данные - это символы размером в один байт, не пойму, как их кодировать. Если циклический код [7,4] строится на 4 информационных битах, а один символ (байт), который нужно передавать, содержит 8 бит.
То есть, к примеру, есть массив символов:

```
byte[] arr = "Test".getBytes();
```

Как закодировать подобную последовательность? Как работает сам алгоритм в битовом представлении, я отлично понимаю.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в чём проблема?

```
(arr[0] >> 4) & 0x0F - первые четыре бита

arr[0] & 0x0F - вторые четыре бита
```

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov если мне не изменяет склероз, [7,4] означает, что каждые 4 информационных бита кодируются 7-ю битами кода. Так что если 1/8 -- небольшая потеря в объёме-скорости передачи, то проще эти 7 бит помещать в один байт. А вообще RS-232 может содержать и 7 бит (плюс стартовый, необязательный чётности и 1-2 стоповых)